# Can I dynamically add permanent rows with Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I am able to dynamically add rows to a table in Wicket. However, once the form is submitted, the newly created rows disappear. I would like to reuse these rows for multiple submissions. Is something like this possible? When trying to find a solution, I found the method `ListView.setReuseItems(true)`. What that does is keep the values from the original rows for the next submission, but newly created rows are still deleted. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code? You need to add new rows to the backing list of the table ..

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn’t post any code, I just assume that you are currently changing the component hierarchy manually, in order to add new rows.

A better approach would be to generate your table from an underlying model object. As long as your model is designed to keep its state between requests, the entire state of the table will be safely stored in the session. This way, in order to add a new row, all you need to do is to add it to the model object and cause the table to be rendered again (e.g via Ajax or page refresh.)

However, if you’re dealing with huge amounts of data, it’s not a good idea to store everything in the session. In that case you need a more sophisticated model, in order to keep the memory footprint as low as possible. But the general idea remains the same: the model handles the data and the component the presentation.